# how to extend a class present in a jar file?

Tags: java, class, jar, overriding

I have a basic question on how to extend a .class present in a jar file?

For example, I have `library.jar` file on my build path and inside this jar file there is a class `ClassA.class`

When i try to do this in eclipse

```
public class ClassAImpl extends ClassA{
}
```

It shows error saying that it cannot find ClassA.

Does it mean that i have to download the sources of the `library.jar` and add those to my project?

Not sure if my question is clear enough?

Comment: if the library is correctly included, this should work! can you provide the classpath? Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: Don't forget to import that class: `import package.of.classA.ClassA;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add `library.jar` to your project build path. "Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > User Libraries". Then, you need to import `ClassA` - and then you can

```
public class ClassAImpl extends ClassA{
}
```

As long as `ClassA` is not `final`.

[image: eclipse Build Path]